# variable in source code - python programming

Tags: python

Currently I am having a problem to avoid "don't repeat yourself".
**This is my code - I want to rephase to be exact my situation now:**

```
if foo == 1:
   for node in content.findAll('a'):
       link = node.get('href')
elif foo == 2:
   for node in content.findAll('li'):
       link = node.li.get('title')
```

is there any way I can do it like this: (I know in PHP I can do similar)

```
if foo == 1:
   char = 'a'
   bar = "node.get('href')"
elif foo == 2:
   char = 'li'
   bar = "node.li.get('title')"

for node in content.findAll(char):
   link = bar
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't repeat code. You perform a different method in each `for` loop.

Comment: You know you can move the conditional check *inside* the for loop right?...Neither of your two code snippets are good coding practice.

Comment: Thank you for your kind word! The problem is: I will have from 3 to maybe 5 for loop:, and the link = node.. is different from case to case.. I want just want 1 for loop: and the other thinks a generalized.

Comment: This is what @Shashank is suggesting, as far as I can tell. Use one `for` loop and check for the value of `foo` inside that.

Comment: Questions of good coding practice aside, you can use [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) to get your second snippet to actually run with the same general formatting: `bar = lambda: node.get('href')`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function:

```
def findAll(content, char, get_code):
    for node in content.findAll(char):
        link = node.li.get(get_code)
    return link
```

Then,

```
if foo == 1:
    link = findAll(content, 'a', 'href')
elif foo == 2:
    link = findAll(content, 'a', 'title')
```

Comment: my problem is: sometimes `link = node.li.get('href')`, sometimes it's `link = node.a.li.h3.get('title')`

Comment: Yes, I've realized this. Your better off to have a single for loop with your conditions in there.

Comment: The pain for me is: `for node in content.findAll('the_value_in_here_also_vary_based_on_the_foo_value!!'):`

Comment: Then you probably need to look again at how `foo` can vary and try to group the branches accordingly. You can just pass a different `char` using the function @Zizouz212 suggested.

Comment: Even I can pass the value in `for node in content.findAll(value)`, I still have problem with `link = node.li.get(get_code)`, because, sometime it's `link=node.a.ul.get('title')`

Comment: @gaixixon I'm gonna make an edit suggesting something, however I'm not sure if it will work. But it could be a starting point for something more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
def find_link(content, entity, attribute, path=()):
    for node in content.findAll(entity):
        for part in path:
            node = getattr(node, part)
    return node.get(attribute)
```

This works for a flat:

```
# get attribute 'href' from 'a'
find_link(content, 'a', 'href')
```

and a nested search:

```
# get attribute 'attr' from div.ul.li
find_link(content, 'div', 'attr', path=['ul', 'li'])
```

The above tries to mimic your logic. As this finds only the last link,
this version might be better:

```
def find_link(content, entity, attribute, path=()):
    links = []
    for node in content.findAll(entity):
        for part in path:
            node = getattr(node, part)
        links.append(node.get(attribute))
    return links
```

It gives you all links.

Finding only th first link could look like this:

```
def find_link(content, entity, attribute, path=()):
    for node in content.findAll(entity):
        for part in path:
            node = getattr(node, part)
        return node.get(attribute)
enter code here
```